# What's the proper syntax in preg_match for validating a string if it contains a alphanumeric value w/ special characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have used this... I saw this in some site.. But it didn't help me very well.

```
if(preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9-_\",'\s]+$/",$newPass)) {
    //is valid..
}
```

Comment: `9-_` `->` `9\-_`... but it would be better if you tell us what the problem is instead of letting us guess. Which strings are matched that you don't want to match or vice versa? You have not given us any example of the input.

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: Im very sorry... My input would be an alphanumeric password with special characters.. example: @s@kapaSaLag045

Comment: @user1892025 what about `/.+/` (that is, match anything at all except newlines)?

Comment: my php code still accepts the password even if it is an alphanumeric string without special characters... the thing is I need special characters in my password.

Comment: So you want to force the string to contain special characters... that's a bit of a different question. Please [**edit your question**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13978338/edit) and clarify it. And yeah, blindly copying code from somewhere without trying to understand it won't get you far. I suggest yo have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Comment: @user1892025 what about `/[^a-z0-9]/i` (match a non-alphanumeric character anywhere in the string)? Or you require the password to contain alphanumeric characters as well?

Comment: @JanDvorak yeah i require a password that contains alphanumeric characters w/ special characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test if a string contains at least one alphanumeric and at least one non-alphanumeric string, use the following regex:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z0-9])(?=.*[^a-z0-9])/i
```

Breakup:

- `/` start of regex
- `^` match the start of the string
- `(?=` if the following is present there:

  - `.*` anything at all (except newlines), then
  - `[a-z0-9]` an alphanumeric character
- `)` end of lookahead
- `(?=` and if the following is present there:

  - `.*` anything at all (except newlines), then
  - `[^a-z0-9]` a non-alphanumeric character
- `)` end of lookahead
- `/` end of regex
- `i` case-insensitive

usage:

```
if(preg_match("/^(?=.*[a-z0-9])(?=.*[^a-z0-9])/i",$newPass)) {
    //is valid..
}
```

If you require letters and digits to both be present, replace the first lookahead by two:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^a-z0-9])/i
```

Comment: I really appreciate this answer with some explanations.. This one works too.. Thank you very much sir!

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the explanations. This is easiest to understand explanation of lookahead I've seen.. all others confused me. Seems simple enough. +1